# Can't pipe to lolcat in bash script

Tags: bash, armbian

I'm trying to modify my motd script in Armbian on my OrangePI. Just wanted to plot name of my machine, instead of big ORANGE PI PC. I found, that I have to edit /etc/update-motd.d/10-armbian-header. There were this lines:

```
if [ $(echo $BOARD_NAME | wc -c) -ge 18 ]; then
    TERM=linux toilet -f standard -F metal $(echo $BOARD_NAME | sed 's/Orange Pi/OPi/' | sed 's/Nanopi/NPi/')
else
    TERM=linux toilet -f standard -F metal $BOARD_NAME
fi
```

So i basically just changed it to

```
TERM=linux toilet -f standard MachineName | lolcat
```

as it's displayed on all my other machines. But it's not working. If I don't pipe it to lolcat it's perfectly good, I have good, but uncollored inscription. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use full path: `/usr/games/lolcat`

Comment: I've tried with 
`TERM=linux toilet -f standard MachineName | /usr/games/lolcat`
but it's completely ignoring lolcat, just printing with normal color

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this on my system by adding the `-f` or `--force` option:

`figlet "HELLO WORLD" | /usr/games/lolcat -f`

I actually found the answer on [StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/543271/lolcat-motd-no-colours) so credit should go to Nick Matteo.